# Migration scripts exits without any message while upgrading Bonitasoft from 6.3.8 - 6.5.3

Tags: business-process-management, bonita, bpmn.io

I tried to migrate bonitasoft from 6.3.8 to 6.5.3. I am on Windows Server , apache 7.0.62 , PostgresSQL. I got all the step by step yes/no prompts all the way till 6.5.3. But the documentation says after migration I should see :

> When the migration script is finished, a message is displayed showing
>   the new platform version, and the time taken for the migration.

I didn't see that message. The script closed without any message. Does this mean my upgrade was not successful ? Also I tried starting the server I keep getting this error :

Node not started. Method 'org.bonitasoft.engine.api.LoginAPI.login' cannot be called until node has been started (PlatformAPI.startNode()).

Has anyone else faced this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a migration bug.
The best thing to do to check that is to open a bug on the [Bonita BPM Community bug tracker](https://bonita.atlassian.net/projects/BBPMC).

Cheers,

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. Was it a bug? If so, could you provide a ticket id?